# How to pass the objects of myArray?

Tags: arrays, fonts, font-size, uifont

I'm a newbie, I have gone through basics but couldn't figure this one out. I've googled so much but finally I land here.

```
fontFamily = [[UIFont alloc]init];  
fontSize = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"10",@"15",@"20",@"25",@"30", nil ];

[text  setFont: [[UIFont familyNames] size:<-----
```

And now, how can I pass the objects to size?

Answer (score 2):

I truly don't know what your looking for. But if you are looking to access the strings you put in the array, you can do so like this:

```
[fontSize objectAtIndex:2]
```

You can put that any place you would want to put `@"20"` since that is what is at index 2.

You should note that you are putting string values in the array not number values.

Edit in response to comment.

You don't really want to just pass the array anywhere what you want to do is something like:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    // if calling for size component
    return fontSize.count;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    // if calling for size component
    return [fontSize objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

If I'm off a little I apologize, I don't use pickerViews much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my question is how do I pass all the objects present in the array?
This is in this way, User selects a font from font family and font size from the fontSize array. Kindly help me.

Comment: @indiaxxo - that doesn't make any sense. You can only set one size at once.

Comment: I'm assuming you are populating a UITableView with this data.

Comment: @jrturton: Yeah now I get it, size can have only 1 int value. If there's a possibility how can I pass an entire array? thank you!

Comment: @NJones: I have populated a component in a PickerView.